# Angular - Update observable manually from an click event

Tags: angular, mouseevent, observable

I am doing the typeahead to show the result when typing into a search box. Basically, I use the Observable.fromEvent to listen to key up event and make the request to the server accordingly.

Upon clicking into one of the results, It will

1. Bring user to the detail page
2. Hide the search result
3. Keep the current search term inside the search box.

For now, I only show the previous search result when user clicking back into the search box and this information might be outdated already.

What I want to archive is every time when clicking on the text box, It will trigger the observable manually If the input is not empty. Found some answers suggest using Subject but don't know how to apply it in my case. Please advise.

```
@Component({
    selector: '[typeahead]',
    templateUrl: 'typeahead.directive.html',
    host: {        
        '(focus)':'onFocus($event)'
    }
})
export class TypeAheadComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {    

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscriptions = [            
            this.listenAndSuggest()
        ];        
    }

    listenAndSuggest() {
        return Observable.fromEvent(this.element.nativeElement, 'keyup')
            .filter(this.validateKeyCode)
            .map((e: any) => e.target.value)
            .debounceTime(400)
            .concat()
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .do(() => {
                this.suggestionIndex = 0;
                this.typeaheadSelecting.emit(true)
            })
            .filter((query: string) => {
                if (!query) this.hideSuggestions()
                return query.length > 0
            })
            .switchMap((query: string) => this.suggest(query))
            .catch((err) => {
                this.typeaheadSelecting.emit(false);
                return Observable.empty();
            })
            .subscribe((results: model.Task[]) => {
                this.results = results;
                this.typeaheadSelecting.emit(false);
                this.showSuggestions = true
            });
    }

    onFocus(event) {
        let value = event.currentTarget.value;        
        if (!value)
            return;
        //to trigger the search again
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses a `Subject` to signal every time `onFocus` is called:

```
export class TypeAheadComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    // Remember to import subject from rxjs
    private onFocus$ = new Subject();

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscriptions = [            
            this.listenAndSuggest()
        ];        
    }

    listenAndSuggest() {
        return Observable.fromEvent(this.element.nativeElement, 'keyup')
            .filter(this.validateKeyCode)
            .map((e: any) => e.target.value)
            .debounceTime(400)
            .concat()
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .merge(onFocus$) // merge the values emitted by onFocus$ with the keyup values
            .do(() => {
                this.suggestionIndex = 0;
                this.typeaheadSelecting.emit(true)
            })
            .filter((query: string) => {
                if (!query) this.hideSuggestions()
                return query.length > 0
            })
            .switchMap((query: string) => this.suggest(query))
            .catch((err) => {
                this.typeaheadSelecting.emit(false);
                return Observable.empty();
            })
            .subscribe((results: model.Task[]) => {
                this.results = results;
                this.typeaheadSelecting.emit(false);
                this.showSuggestions = true
            });
    }

    onFocus(event) {
        let value = event.currentTarget.value;        
        if (!value)
            return;
        onfocus$.next(value); // emit value every time onFocus is called
    }
}
```

Comment: I move the .merge(onFocus$) to below of distinctUntilChanged and see it works. Thanks

Comment: Ah, yes. That's the correct place to put it. Updated my answer